# SQL query that can select n rows order by and then return m row

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I need to create SQL query that can select lets say 1000 rows orders by one column and then returns only 100 rows.

Why? My query can select ~1 000 000 row (or more) and I want to take first 1000 and from this 1000 rows show only 100 with the best relevance. I'm afraid about performance of such a select so I want to introduce this first step (take only 1000 rows). I know that I might miss document with better relevance but in this case it doesn't matter.

Comment: Are you asking for a query that selects the first 1000 rows for a given ordering, then returns the first 100 rows of that result by a *different* ordering?

Comment: @ Cyberkiwi I use MS Sql. @AdamRobinson. No I want to select 1000 row order and then return 100 row.

Comment: Still do not understand "select 1000 row order and then return 100 row." Why?

Comment: This question still doesn't make any sense. You need to explain what difference you think it makes to select 1000 rows then return the first 100 versus just selecting the first 100. Perhaps it would help us understand this seemingly nonsensical request if you gave an example of the table contents and the expected output (assume 2 and 5 instead of 100/1000 for the purposes of your example)

Comment: -1: there are at least a dozen people asking why you need to select 1000 rows when you're going to throw them away, so its not clear what you're actually trying to do or what sort of answer you expect. Please rephrase your question. And remember, its better to describe your goal rather than the step to get there: http://www.catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html#goal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The literal interpretation would lead to

```
select top 1000 from tbl order by columnname
```

And the next step to

```
SELECT TOP 100 FROM (select top 1000 from tbl order by columnname) SQ
```

But that gives no different than a direct

```
select top 100 from tbl order by columnname
```

Unless you are after 2 different orderings

```
SELECT TOP 100
FROM (
   select top 1000 from tbl
   order by columnname) SQ
ORDER BY othercolumn
```

or switching between asc/desc

```
SELECT TOP 100
FROM (
   select top 1000 from tbl
   order by columnname ASC) SQ
ORDER BY columnname DESC
```

Comment: You are supposed to put a wild card or specify column name after top 100 otherwise sql server will throw an error. i.e `select top 1000 * from tbl order by columnname`

Answer (score 5):

Does it matter if you don't select the first 1000? i.e. if you just use...

```
Select top 100 *
From table
Order by column
```

You get the same result and as pointed out elsewhere you won't are likely to degrade performance rather than improve it.

If you want to optimize this query then ensure that there is an index on the `column` then the SQL server will be able to optimise the retrieval and sorting of the records to give you just what you want.

Comment: So DB engine is so smart that it can automatically optimize this query ?

Comment: @Darqer: What is the purpose of the 1000?

Comment: Why would the DB engine need to be smart to return exactly what you asked for? No special optimization is needed.

Comment: Well I need kind of optimization. I have huge DB and select some data but I want to select only 1000 row (example it might be 2000 as well) and then order it by some column (relevance) and then return only 100 user does not need more.

Comment: Why do you need to select the 1000, why not only the 100? The end result is 100% identical. I think you are making this more complicated than it needs to be.

Answer (score 4):

I think I finally understand what you are trying to get at, but it appears you are very confused about how databases perform ordering operations.

If I understand you correctly, you are concerned about the performance impact of sorting a large number of rows (1,000 in your example, though that is NOT a large number of rows). So you are trying to outsmart it by only making it sort the 100 rows you are interested in.

If you apply a where clause to limit it to 100 rows, in most cases a modern DB system will automatically hold off on performing the sort until after it has narrowed down the results to avoid doing extra work. This is not true 100% of the time, but when the DB optimizer decides to sort first, it usually has a VERY good reason based on performance or because the query has identified a condition whereby the sort must be performed first to get 
accurate results.

The trick is that you have to understand that tSQL is a Declarative language not a procedural one. That is, you use the language to describe what you want, and the optimizer figures out the exact algorithm to make that happen. It appears that you are trying to optimize your code the way you would as if you were writing a procedural language like C# or Java. SQL translates your query into code, it doesn't run it as you type it.

Long story short, the DB engines are extremely good at this type of simple optimization (and some very complex ones). You aren't going to out-optimize the optimizer with gimmicks like this, so don't even bother. You aren't going to get more performance and depending on how you write the query, you could actually degrade it.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a subquery.  Something like:

```
select top 100 * from (
    select * from tablename
    limit 1000
)
order by fieldname
```

My SQL is a bit rusty so the syntax might be off a bit, and there may be a better way to do it depending on the platform you're working with, but hopefully this helps.

Comment: This query is a rather obfuscated way to do Select top 100 from TableName order by fieldname and really provides no benefit.

Comment: @JohnFx: I was assuming the OP had some other criteria in mind for select the original 1000 records which would then add a `where` clause to the sub query.  Probably should have been more explicit.

Comment: It still wouldn't make any difference in the output.